# Parse XML Dom with PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom, xml-parsing

Seem to be having an issue capturing the field "admin" under contact type

```
<epp:epp xmlns:epp="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">
<epp:response>
<epp:result code="1000">
  <epp:msg>Domain Info Command completed successfully</epp:msg>
</epp:result>
<epp:resData>
  <domain:infData xmlns:domain="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0">
    <domain:name>exampledomain.com</domain:name>
    <domain:roid>DOM_1E-PDT</domain:roid>
    <domain:status s="ok"/>
    <domain:registrant>exampleregistrant</domain:registrant>
    <domain:contact type="admin">admincontact</domain:contact>
    <domain:contact type="tech">techcontact</domain:contact>
    <domain:contact type="billing">billingcontact</domain:contact>
    <domain:contact type="reseller">resellercontact</domain:contact>
```

Code I tried was:

```
$adminid = $doc->getElementsByTagName('admin')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are the other fields working with the same code, then? How exactly are you loading in `$doc`? What type did you turn it into? This definitely matters. - also, what errors are you getting?

Comment: “admin” is not a tag name, it is an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In the node `<domain:contact type="admin">`, “admin” is not a node. It is the value of attribute “type” (of node <domain:contact>).

So, to retrieve its node value, you have to find for an element with TagName=“domain:contact” and attribute “type=admin”.

The colon in the Tag Name denote a NameSpaced node: you can not search for it simply by using `->getElementsByTagName( 'domain:contact' )`, you have also to specify relative NameSpace URI. You can find NamespaceURI in one of node ancestors, in an attribute identified by `xmlns:` followed by Namespace Tag prefix (in your case, `domain`).

In your XML, NameSpaceURI is in:

```
<domain:infData xmlns:domain="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0">
<!--            └─┬─┘ └─┬──┘  └──────┬────────────────────────┘
 NS declaration prefix  NS prefix    NameSpace URI
```

To find a NameSpaced Element, you can use this syntax:

```
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagNameNS( 'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0', 'contact' );
foreach( $nodes as $node )
{
    if( 'admin' == $node->getAttribute( 'type' ) ) $adminid = $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Otherwise, you can use DOMXPath:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc );
$xpath->registerNameSpace( 'd', 'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0' );
#                          ┌┘
$nodes = $xpath->query( '//d:contact[@type="admin"]' );
$adminid = $found->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

As you can see, you can use any alias to refer to NameSpace prefix, not necessary the real prefix (In above example, I use 'd' instead of 'domain').

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
$rawXml = 
<<<XML
    <epp:epp xmlns:epp="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">
        <epp:response>
            <epp:result code="1000">
                <epp:msg>Domain Info Command completed successfully</epp:msg>
            </epp:result>
            <epp:resData>
                <domain:infData xmlns:domain="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0">
                    <domain:name>exampledomain.com</domain:name>
                    <domain:roid>DOM_1E-PDT</domain:roid>
                    <domain:status s="ok"/>
                    <domain:registrant>exampleregistrant</domain:registrant>
                    <domain:contact type="admin">admincontact</domain:contact>
                    <domain:contact type="tech">techcontact</domain:contact>
                    <domain:contact type="billing">billingcontact</domain:contact>
                    <domain:contact type="reseller">resellercontact</domain:contact>
                </domain:infData>
            </epp:resData>
        </epp:response>
    </epp:epp>
XML;



 $xmlDoc = new SimpleXMLElement($rawXml);

 $xmlDoc->registerXPathNamespace('domain', 'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0');
 echo $xmlDoc->xpath('//domain:contact[@type="admin"]')[0];
```